# retrieve $event object from emit event in parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am emitting an event in a child component so I can, if I need to, prevent it from happening in the parent.
Is there a way to retrieve event object so I can prevent it in the parent component like this ?

```js
// child component event
this.$emit('navigationTab');

// parent template event bind
@onTab="on_tab($event)"

// parent handler method
on_tab(event) {
  event.preventDefault
  // ...logic etc
}
```

It only works if y pass the event object like this I wish to catch $event directly without sending the object inside the event, which is probably already sent in the emit

```js
// child component event
this.$emit('navigationTab', event);

// parent template bind
@navigationTab="on_tab"

// parent handler method
on_tab(event) {
  event.preventDefault
  // ...logic etc
}
```

Comment: Event argument is automatically passed as an parameter into handler method - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Comment: I saw that, it works with native events @click but does not seem to work with custom emitted events like I tried in the second example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Event argument is automatically passed as an parameter into handler method (see example bellow)
2. You can't use `preventDefault()` on custom events, only on native browser events. And of course you don't need to because there is not any "default" behavior for custom events (emitted with `$emit`)

```js
const myComponent = Vue.component('myComponent', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="$emit('myEvent', 'event payload')">Click me!</button>
    </div>
  `
})

const app = new Vue({
  components: {myComponent} ,
  template: `
    <div>
      <myComponent @myEvent="handle" />
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    handle(event) {
      console.log("Event received:", event)
    }
  }
})
app.$mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: ok so I am forced to pass the native event object inside my custom event so I can prevent. it. Thanks.